# MySQL : Get max values of groups

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table:

```
user_id | fav_song_genre | votes_as_fav_member
--------+----------------+--------------------
      1 | hip hop        | 3
      2 | hip hop        | 5
      3 | rock           | 8
      4 | rock           | 6
```

How do I get only results of user_id's with the highest votes_as_fav_member per group fav_song_genre:

Something like

```
SELECT *, MAX(votes_as_fav_member) as most_votes 
FROM   table 
GROUP BY 
       fav_song_genre
```

I'm using that but it's not giving me the ID's of the members with most votes per genre.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reasoning goes like

- `SELECT` max vote for each genre
- `JOIN` back with the original table to retrieve the additional columns for the records found.

**SQL Statement**

```
SELECT  us.*
FROM    UserSongs us
        INNER JOIN (
          SELECT  fav_song_genre
                  , MAX(votes_as_fav_member) AS votes_as_fav_member
          FROM    UserSongs
          GROUP BY
                  fav_song_genre
        ) usm ON usm.fav_song_genre = us.fav_song_genre
                 AND usm.votes_as_fav_member = us.votes_as_fav_member
```

**Edit**

*How can I make sure the person with the lower ID is returned*

```
SELECT  MIN(us.user_id) as user_id
        , us.fav_song_genre
        , us.votes_as_fav_member
FROM    UserSongs us
        INNER JOIN (
          SELECT  fav_song_genre
                  , MAX(votes_as_fav_member) AS votes_as_fav_member
          FROM    UserSongs
          GROUP BY
                  fav_song_genre
        ) usm ON usm.fav_song_genre = us.fav_song_genre
                 AND usm.votes_as_fav_member = us.votes_as_fav_member
GROUP BY
        us.fav_song_genre
        , votes_as_fav_member
```

Comment: Ah!!! I appreciate this sooo much! Thank you. I'm still having an issue with learning inner joins. 

If I want to have only 1 item returned per group, how can I make sure the person with the lower ID is returned?

Comment: @Darius in the subquery add `MIN(user_id) AS min_user_id` and then on the `ON` clause add `AND usm.min_iser_id = us.user_id`

Comment: Got it, I didn't need to add the "AND usm.user_id = us.user_id" because it would only return one value. I needed each genre to show a result, and if there were two people with same amount of votes in a genre, it would choose the one with the lower id to represent that genre. So, the addition of "MIN(user_id) AS user_id" was enough. Thank you again.

Comment: @Darius, I believe you and I both made an error. By returning the MIN(user_id) in the subquery, you could get the wrong results. I've corrected it with my latest edit.

Answer (score 5):

This is not a problem of MySQL, rather a bit of logic problem with your approach.

Let's say we have the following:

```
user_id | fav_song_genre | votes_as_fav_member
--------+----------------+--------------------
      1 | hip hop        | 3
      2 | hip hop        | 5
      3 | rock           | 8
      4 | rock           | 6
      5 | hip hop        | 5
      6 | rock           | 8
```

Which ID should the query return? Should it return only one? or all that have the same amount of votes?

So, if you require only a single ID, what is the differentiation of a draw?

Lieven beat me to the SQL resolution by a few seconds, though.

Comment: you did explain the problem I described as a note much better. +1 for that.

Comment: I appreciate your explanation and help Paulo.

Answer (score 1):

I created the table and tested, and I think this will also work

Table Data:

```
user_id fav_song_genre  votes_as_fav_member
1   hip_hop 3
2   hip_hop 5
3   rock    8
4   rock    6
5   blues   20
6   indie   18
7   rock    35
8   country 33
9   hip_hop 35
10  indie   5
11  blues   7
12  hip_hop 59
13  indie   187
14  classic 45
15  country 61
16  hip_hop 243
```

Query:

```
select t.user_id, t.fav_song_genre, t.votes_as_fav_member
from (
    select user_id, max(votes_as_fav_member) as max_votes, fav_song_genre 
    from table1 group by fav_song_genre
)
as x inner join table1 as t on t.votes_as_fav_member = x.max_votes and t.fav_song_genre = x.fav_song_genre;
```

Results:

```
user_id fav_song_genre  votes_as_fav_member
5   blues   20
7   rock    35
13  indie   187
14  classic 45
15  country 61
16  hip_hop 243
```

Comment: This will NOT sum the votes, nor find the Maximum. It will only count rows (probably ids) with same fav_song_genre. So, it will give the most popular fav_genre.

Comment: do note that the concerns others have posted about a "tie" still apply. but if you only want one result, and you don't care who wins the "tie breaker" .. then this should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that's what you are asking:

```
SELECT g.fav_song_genre
     , t.user_id
     , g.most_votes
FROM yourTable t
  JOIN 
    ( SELECT fav_song_genre
           , MAX(votes_as_fav_member) as most_votes
      FROM yourTable
      GROUP BY fav_song_genre
    ) AS g
    ON t.fav_song_genre = g.fav_song_genre
      AND t.votes_as_fav_member= g.most_votes
;
```