# SQL Query on a single table

Tags: mysql, sql

I need an SQL query for the below problem

```
Table: EMPLOYEE  
DeptCode   Level  EmpID Name  
Mkt    VP      1    JOHN  
Mkt    GM      2    BOB  
Mkt    CLERK   3    TIM  
IT     GM      4    BILLY  
IT     GM      5    JESSICA  
IT     CLERK   6    MONICA  
HR     VP      7    NIKITA  
HR     GM      8    TOM  
HR     GM      9    HARRY
```

Question: For each dept I want to find the employee who is at the highest level in that department. If there are 2 or more emp at the highest level in a particular dept. then no records should come for that dept

The hierarchy of Level is:  VP > GM > CLERK

So I should get following results

```
DeptCode    Level   EmpID   Name  
Mkt VP  1   JOHN  
HR  VP  7   NIKITA
```

For IT, there is no emp at level VP. Next level is GM but there are two emp at this level, so no record is selected for IT dept

I would greatly appreciate if you could suggest an answer or way forward on this.

Comment: Have you attempted anything so far? Please share whatever you have attempted.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448354/mysql-get-max-values-of-groups

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. **You start it, and then we help. We don't write it for you.** Show us the actual code that you've tried, and then describe what happened and what's not right, and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  e.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT
                deptCode
        FROM    employee
        ) ed
JOIN    employee e
ON      e.empId =
        (
        SELECT  empId
        FROM    employee ei
        WHERE   ei.deptCode = ed.deptCode
        ORDER BY
                FIND_IN_SET(level, 'VP,GM,CLERK')
        LIMIT 1
        )
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  NULL
        FROM    employee eo
        WHERE   (eo.deptCode, eo.level) = (e.deptCode, e.level)
                AND eo.empId <> e.empId
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Make another table for Levels with a field for Rank.

```
Level   Rank
VP      1
GM      2
CLERK   3
```

Then make a view (i.e. vHighestRankPerDept) that looks like this:

```
SELECT Levels.Level AS HighestLevel, t.DeptCode
FROM (SELECT MIN(Levels.Rank) AS Highest, Employee.DeptCode
      FROM Levels INNER JOIN Employee ON Employee.Level = Levels.Level
      GROUP BY Employee_1.DeptCode) AS t
INNER JOIN Levels ON Levels.Rank = t.Highest
```

Then:

```
SELECT Employee.DeptCode, Employee.Level, MAX(Employee.EmpID) AS EmpID, MAX(Employee.Name) AS Name
FROM Employee
INNER JOIN vHighestRankPerDept ON vHighestRankPerDept.DeptCode = Employee.DeptCode
  AND Employee.Level = vHighestRankPerDept.HighestLevel
GROUP BY Employee.DeptCode, Employee.Level
HAVING COUNT(Employee.Level) = 1
```